# How to display all images (files) in Baqend?

Tags: angular, ionic3, baqend

I'm building an app using Ionic 3 with Baqend. I know how to get the list of all images inside a folder using:

```
let folder;
folder = new this.db.File('/file/www/event_0001/');
this.db.File.listFiles(folder).then(function(files) {
    console.log(files);
});
```

I don't want to keep a reference of each image inside my database since I'm uploading manually through Baqend console. So how can I iterate through the folder, extract the url of each image, and display them using `<img src=.../>` ?

Comment: Why do you not want to use listFiles for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `file.url` method to generate an URL:

```js
let folder;
folder = new this.db.File('/file/www/event_0001/');
this.db.File.listFiles(folder).then(function(files) {
    this.images = files.map(file => file.url); 
});
```

Afterwards you can use `ngFor` to display the images:

```html
<div *ngFor="let image of images">  
   <img [src]="image">
</div>
```

and you must set the query permission on the folder correctly for listFiles to work. For example to public or a group/user who should be allowed to do this.

Comment: What's the type of `this.images` ? I tried `images: any[];` but I get the error `Cannot set property 'images' of undefined`.

Comment: The error went away when I used arrows instead 'function'. It's working thanks. I have another question, how do I ignore the .keep file that resides within the folder? Because it is trying to display it as an image.

Comment: listFiles has no filter function, so you have to do it in the client:

    `this.db.File.listFiles(folder).then(function(files) {
        this.images = files.filter(file => file.name !== '.keep').map(file => file.url); 
    });`